# ESB WSO2 - Using ARRAY as paramType in a datasource query

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I want to sent a request to my api like this:

```
{
    "id": "22",
    "code": "AXB23, ADR40, SMRS2"
}
```

And I want to use every code in a query like "SELECT ... WHERE ... IN(AXB23, ADR40, SMRS2)"  in my datasource but I don't know how.
I found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/Writing+Queries) a solution with `<param type="IN" name="code" paramType="ARRAY" sqlType="STRING"/>`
but it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

EDIT*:
This is my api (inSequence - forget about the id from request in the original post, I just only have that 'code')

```
<inSequence>
    <property expression="json-eval($..code)" name="code" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <selectTEST xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/selectTEST">
                <code>$1</code>
            </selectTEST>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:code"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
            
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/xml"/>
    <header name="Action" scope="default" value="selectTEST"/>
    <call>
        <endpoint key="ep.select"/>
    </call>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            
    <respond/>
</inSequence>
```

and this is my dataservice:

```
<operation name="selectTEST" returnRequestStatus="true">
        <call-query href="selectTEST">
            <with-param name="code" query-param="code"/>
        </call-query>
</operation>

<query id="selectTEST" useConfig="default">
        <sql><![CDATA[
        select x, y, z, w from mydatabase where code in (:code)
        ]]></sql>
            <param type="IN" name="code" paramType="ARRAY" sqlType="STRING"/>
        <result outputType="json">
        {
          "data": {
            "records": [
              {
                "x": "$x",
                "y": "$y",
                "z": "$z",
                "w": "$w"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
        </result>
</query>
```

My request:

```
{ 
    "code": ["AXB23", "ADR40"]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code for the query? If you use a DSS please show the DSS as well? Also, tell us how it doesn't work, do you get an error, or does something else happen.

Comment: Sorry for the laster reply. I just edited my post ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the array type parameters you should pass the values as a proper JSON array. Something like this will work for you.

**The Request:**

```
{
  "_poststudent": {
    "code": ["AXB23","ADR40"]
  }
}
```

**Dataservice Query**

```
<query id="CreateStudents" useConfig="default">
    <sql>SELECT id, name, school, grade FROM students WHERE grade IN (:code)</sql>
    <param name="code" paramType="ARRAY" sqlType="STRING" type="IN" optional="false" />
    <result outputType="json">{"students":{"student":[{"name":"$name","school":"$school","grade":"$grade"}]}}{"students":{"student":[{"name":"$name","school":"$school","grade":"$grade"}]}}{"students":{"student":[{"name":"$name","school":"$school","grade":"$grade"}]}}{"students":{"student":[{"name":"$name","school":"$school",                        "grade":"$grade"}]}}{"students":{"student":[{"name":"$name","school":"$school","grade":"$grade"}]}}{"students":{"student":[{"name":"$name","school":"$school","grade":"$grade"}]}}{"students":{"student":[{"name":"$name","school":"$school", "grade":"$grade"} ] }}{"students":{"student":[{"name":"$name","school":"$school","grade":"$grade"} ] } }</result>
  </query>
```

**Update**

The Full Dataservice config.

```xml
<data name="RESTDataService" serviceNamespace="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/json_sample" transports="http https">
  <description>Exposing the data service as a REST service.</description>
  <config id="default">
    <property name="driverClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_db</property>
    <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.user">xxxxx</property>
    <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.password">xxxxx</property>
  </config>
  <resource method="POST" path="student">
    <call-query href="ReadStudents">
      <with-param name="code" query-param="code" />
    </call-query>
  </resource>
  <operation name="selectTEST" returnRequestStatus="true">
    <call-query href="ReadStudents">
      <with-param name="code" query-param="code" />
    </call-query>
  </operation>
  <query id="ReadStudents" useConfig="default">
    <sql>SELECT id, name, school, grade FROM students WHERE grade IN (:code)</sql>
    <param name="code" paramType="ARRAY" sqlType="STRING" type="IN" optional="false" />
    <result outputType="json">{               "students":{                  "student":[                     {                        "name":"$name",                        "school":"$school",                        "grade":"$grade"                     }                  ]               }            }      {               "students":{                  "student":[                     {                        "name":"$name",                        "school":"$school",                        "grade":"$grade"                     }                  ]               }            }      {               "students":{                  "student":[                     {                        "name":"$name",                        "school":"$school",                        "grade":"$grade"                     }                  ]               }            }      {               "students":{                  "student":[                     {                        "name":"$name",                        "school":"$school",                        "grade":"$grade"                     }                  ]               }            }      {               "students":{                  "student":[                     {                        "name":"$name",                        "school":"$school",                        "grade":"$grade"                     }                  ]               }            }      {               "students":{                  "student":[                     {                        "name":"$name",                        "school":"$school",                        "grade":"$grade"                     }                  ]               }            }      {               "students":{                  "student":[                     {                        "name":"$name",                        "school":"$school",                        "grade":"$grade"                     }                  ]               }            }      {               "students":{                  "student":[                     {                        "name":"$name",                        "school":"$school",                        "grade":"$grade"                     }                  ]               }            }      {               "students":{                  "student":[                     {                        "name":"$name",                        "school":"$school",                        "grade":"$grade"                     }                  ]               }            }      {               "students":{                  "student":[                     {                        "name":"$name",                        "school":"$school",                        "grade":"$grade"                     }                  ]               }            }      {               "students":{                  "student":[                     {                        "name":"$name",                        "school":"$school",                        "grade":"$grade"                     }                  ]               }            }      {               "students":{                  "student":[                     {                        "name":"$name",                        "school":"$school",                        "grade":"$grade"                     }                  ]               }            }      {               "students":{                  "student":[                     {                        "name":"$name",                        "school":"$school",                        "grade":"$grade"                     }                  ]               }            }      {               "students":{                  "student":[                     {                        "name":"$name",                        "school":"$school",                        "grade":"$grade"                     }                  ]               }            }      {               "students":{                  "student":[                     {                        "name":"$name",                        "school":"$school",                        "grade":"$grade"                     }                  ]               }            }      {               "students":{                  "student":[                     {                        "name":"$name",                        "school":"$school",                        "grade":"$grade"                     }                  ]               }            }      </result>
  </query>
</data>
```

Note that I have specified a `<resource method="POST" path="student">`. resources are for RESTfull invocations, and `<operation name="selectTEST" returnRequestStatus="true">` are for SOAP calls. I have created both RestFul and SOAP services for your reference. Following is how you can invoke them.

Note: Here I'm directly calling the Dataservice.

**RestFull Invocation.**

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8290/services/RESTDataService/student' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "students": {
    "code": ["AXB23", "ADR40"]
  }
}'
```

**SOAP Service Call**

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8290/services/RESTDataService/selectTEST' \
--header 'Action: selectTEST' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/xml' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--data-raw '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <code>AXB23</code>
        <code>ADR40</code>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'
```

Note: In a XML message an Array is depicted as repeating elements as shown above.

Comment: I just edited my post. I tried your suggestion too, but still doesn't work

Comment: Also, I put a Log mediator after I store the value of the code and in my logs I have this on my Log Mediator:
Start : Log mediator
Log_: = ["AXB23","ADR40"]
End : Log mediator
Is it okay like this?

Comment: So your Dataservice is a SOAP service? And you want to receive a Rest API call to your API and convert it to a SOAP message and call the Dataservice and then get a JSON response from the Dataservice?

Comment: Pretty yes. I'm a newbie tho

Comment: If you want to deal with JSON messages, it's best to create RESTfull Data services. I'll update my answer.